# htaccess 403 error redirect does not work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I create 404 redirect in my htaccess and this work fine.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /myfolder/404.html
```

But I have problem with 403 redirect.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /myfolder/403.html
```

This line does not work properly. Do you have some idea. Thanks.

Comment: Are the permissions on the 403.html file the same as the 404.html file?

Comment: Can you define "does not work properly"?

Comment: Redirection does not work. I have this message Error 403
 
localhost
28.2.2013 9:28:43
 Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1